# AddOwnedForm - add WPF Window?

Tags: wpf, winforms, forms, parent-child

I'm working with an existing WinForms form.  I'm trying to interface a new WPF Window with it (to replace an old form).  The old code called `mainForm.AddOwnedForm(newForm);`.

I know that that makes the new form somewhat of a child of the main form -- it's hidden when the main form is, etc.

Is there a way for me to link a WPF window to the main form in the same way?

Obviously, WinForms doesn't know about WPF, so I'm not expecting an AddOwnedWindow method or anything.  But is there a way to emulate this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`WindowInteropHelper` will do it:

```
var newWindow = new WPFWindow();
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(newWindow) {Owner = mainForm.Handle};
```

Thanks to [this source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhendersblog/archive/2005/10/04/476921.aspx).